# LaTeX memoir page numbers at bottom margin instead of footer

Tags: header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

Does anyone know how to get the memoir class to place page numbers at the top of the lower margin instead of within the footer region?

Here is a link to my .cls: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/8SpsLitf)

Here is a link to MWE: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/nHybv1xu)

The format committee sent me this image to give me an idea of what they're wanting: [image: page number position]

Comment: please add the example inline not as an external link (the question and answers are archived forever) it isn't clear what you want to change page numbers are usually in the page foot which would be just above the bottom margin, where that arrow points?

Comment: With `fancyhdr` package, you can put page numbers in your own footer. Instead of just `\thepage` there, use `\raisebox` to move it. Also consider using `\smash` too. @DavidCarlisle - This strategy is built into you-know-what.

Comment: @RobtAll fancyhdr should not be used with the memoir class, it has its own well integrated system for handling headers and footers. This question is quite easy to solve by making your own pagestyle and perhaps aliasing some of the build in one.

Comment: @RobtAll the question (and your comment) are rather unclear, it isn't at all clear why the page number should be raised above the page foot. If the OP has a review comment that the page number is too low then it would appear that reducing `\textwidth` via the facilities memoir offers (or even just doing that directly) is all that is needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed both unclear. A code response would be too user-specific. General idea: Layout bottom margin smaller than desired, footskip larger than desired, so that location of footer sits within the "desired" bottom margin. But the visible content of footer can be raised, relative to the footer position, using `\raisebox`. Then the visible content of footer can be placed to create the illusion of a larger bottom margin, or it can be lowered, as needed. But I don't think this is worth pursuing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you meant to say `\textheight` rather than `\textwidth`.